# Calling action creator for onClick event on a material-ui button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

When I called an action creator for an onClick event on material ui RaisedButton, I got the following error

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onClick` of type `object` supplied to `RaisedButton`, expected `function`.

This is the component that I've written

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../actions';

class App extends Component {
  authButton = () => {
    if(this.props.authenticated) {
      return <RaisedButton label="Sign out" onClick={this.props.authenticate(false)} />
    }

    return <RaisedButton label="Sign out" onClick={this.props.authenticate(true)} />
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.authButton()}</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { authenticated: state.authenticated };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

How to get rid of this error and make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its expecting a function, so try this

`onClick={() => { this.props.authenticate(false)}}`